# linking the hover effect between two fields with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the style of field when hoving over another field. This works fine when I use anchor tags, but with table tags it does not seem to work?
This version works:

```
<p>Hover over 1 and 3 gets styled.</p>
<a id="one">1</a>
<a id="two">2</a>
<a id="three">3</a>
```

with the css

```
#one:hover ~ #three{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

now I would like to get the same with tables:

```
 <table>
   <tr align="center">
      <td>
         <a id="four">
             4
         </a>
      </td>  
   </tr>
   <tr align="center">
      <td>
         <a id="five">
            5
         </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and the css

```
#five:hover ~ #four{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

but the table doesn't work... here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/a3y52/1044/

Comment: This can't work, for two reasons: **1:** the elements aren't siblings, and you're using the general sibling combinator. **2:** there's no 'previous-sibling' selector (so even if they were siblings the general sibling combinator still wouldn't/couldn't work).

Comment: You can't select **up** the document. You'd need javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript, or better Jquery to do this :

in your script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $( "#five" ).hover(
      function() {
        $('#four').addClass( "overstate" );
      }, function() {
        $('#four').removeClass( "overstate" );
      }
    );
});
```

In your css:

```
#five:hover {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

.overstate {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: thanks Nathan... works fine for me... I am a bit surprised though that css is so inflexible...

Comment: Your welcome. Css is still very flexible, but it only works with parent-child relations.

Answer (score 1):

If you will add  a to CSS that will work

```css
#one:hover ~ #three{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

a#five:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
a#four:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr align="center">
      <td>
         <a id="four">
             4
         </a>
      </td>  
   </tr>
   <tr align="center">
      <td>
         <a id="five">
            5
         </a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```